# How can I hold the value of counter in testbench of VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

The counter only last for one clock cycle but I want the `test_counter` remain unchanged until next `button_case`.

`test_counter` should transition like this  "0000" -> "0010" -> "0001" ->"0100" -> "1000" -> "0000"

I have tried this below but it's not working.

```
when others      => null; -- do nothing
```

`when others => knapp_in_1_n <= knapp_in_1_n;` gives me the following wave.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity testbench_keypad_v2 is
end entity;

-- testbench for keypad scan

architecture rtl OF testbench_keypad_v2 is

-- constants 
constant sys_clk_period : TIME := 100 ns;

-- signals 
signal sys_clk           : std_logic;
signal led               : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal knapp_in_1_n      : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := b"0000";


signal reset_n           : std_logic;

constant default_value   : unsigned(25 downto 0) := 26d"200000";   -- 20ms

signal  test_counter     : unsigned(25 downto 0) := 26d"0";
signal prev_test_counter : unsigned(25 downto 0) := (others => '0');

component keypad_v1
port (
    clk, reset_n         : in  std_logic;
    key_in               : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    key_out              : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    led_display          : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end component;

begin

    i1 : keypad_v1
    PORT MAP (
        -- list connections between master ports and signals
        clk                => sys_clk,
        led_display        => led,
        key_in             => knapp_in_1_n,
        reset_n            => reset_n
    );
 
    clock: process
    begin
        -- Clock period 
        sys_clk <= '0'; 
        wait for sys_clk_period/2;
        sys_clk <= '1';
        wait for sys_clk_period/2;
         -- Här upprepas processen, ”GO TO Start”
    end process;

    reset: process
    begin
         -- Reset at start up
        reset_n <= '0';
        wait for 5*sys_clk_period;
        -- Target running
        reset_n <= '1';
        wait; -- test case 5
        -- ett tomt “WAIT;” stannar processen, eftersom det finns inget villkor
    end process;

    counter_cases : process(sys_clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(sys_clk) then
            if test_counter < default_value then
                test_counter <= test_counter + 1;
            else
                test_counter <= (others => '0') after 150 ns; -- 150 ns is 1.5 sys_clk
            end if; 
        end if;
    end process;

    button_case: process(test_counter)
    begin
        case test_counter is
            when 26d"100001" => knapp_in_1_n <= "0001";
            when 26d"266668" => knapp_in_1_n <= "0010";
            when 26d"800014" => knapp_in_1_n <= "1000";
            when 26d"600015" => knapp_in_1_n <= "0100";
            when others      => knapp_in_1_n <= "0000"; -- do nothing
      end case;
    end process;      

end rtl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your `test_counter` to reset, then you shouldn't do it

```
...
else
                test_counter <= (others => '0') after 150 ns; -- 150 ns is 1.5 sys_clk
...
```

But do be honest, I'm not really sure what you want to achieve. It seems you want `button_case` to depend on `test_counter` and vice-versa.

**Update:**

If you want `knapp_in_1_n` to keep its value after a case assignment, change the `others` statement to

```
when others => knapp_in_1_n <= knapp_in_1_n;
```

But you then need an additional condition/case to set `knapp_in_1_n` back to `"0000"` but only you know when this is.

Comment: I want it to keep its value until next transition. `test_counter` should transition like this  "0000" -> "0010" -> "0001" ->"0100" -> "1000" -> "0000"

Comment: you mean `knapp_in_1_n` should transition like this? I updated the answer

Comment: It doesn't work even with `when others => knapp_in_1_n <= knapp_in_1_n;`
See my updated question

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the new sequence? `knapp_in_1_n` now seems to be stable after change...

Comment: knapp_in_1_n should change to   `knapp_in_1_n <= "0100"` when `test_counter `reaches  `26d"600015"`

However,
It doesn't change in the wave form

Comment: Did you check that it reaches this value? Because you still seem to reset it once it reaches 200000 (`default_value`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Indeed, `default_value` is the bug which causes this weird problem.